# Insert into table with minus

Tags: sql, oracle

I am trying to insert some data into a table with a minus operation. I have my table (SG_AN_KZ) and a stag table which I use to retrieve some data to do the minus. I also retrieve the data from a inner join in order to make the minus operation. The problem is that the query does not work and I can't figure out the reason. Here the entire query:

```
INSERT INTO SG_AN_KZ (ID, CODE, TIPO_RECORD, SYSCREATEDATE, SYSCREATEUSER, SYSUPDATEDATE, SYSUPDATEUSER, FLAG_DELETED, ID_PN) 
 (SELECT (SELECT ROWNUM + ID_KZ, CODE, TIPO_RECORD, systimestamp, 967, systimestamp, 967, 0, ID_PN) FROM
     (SELECT Q1.CODE, Q1.TIPO_RECORD, systimestamp, 967, systimestamp, 967,0,Q2.ID
      FROM
       (SELECT DISTINCT S.CODE, S.TIPO_RECORD FROM STAG_SG_AN_KZ S
       INNER JOIN SG_AN_PN P 
       ON P.CODE = S.CODE)Q1,
       (SELECT DISTINCT P.ID FROM SG_AN_PN P
       INNER JOIN STAG_SG_AN_KZ S
       ON S.CODE = P.CODE) Q2,
       STAG_SG_AN_KZ S 
      WHERE S.CODE = Q1.CODE)  
     MINUS
     SELECT CODE, TIPO_RECORD, ID_PN from SG_AN_KZ; 

Errore(118,2): PL/SQL: SQL Statement ignored
Errore(119,99): PL/SQL: ORA-00923: parola chiave FROM non trovata dove prevista
```

Do you have any idea?
thank you in advance.

Comment: Horribly wrong query. Mention what do you want..And tell the table structure.

Comment: You have a lot of nested query,that probably you don't really need. Try to split your query using CTEs, this will clarify the query structure and help you in understanding the problem.

Comment: Start by counting the parentheses,, which aren't balanced; but are also in the wrong places. But you might want to rethink and simplify...